# Getting an undefined in object method

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Why I'm getting an `undefined`? So I think this is a problem inside the arrow functions...
 I need to amke it work by the arrow function inside the method `say`

```
const obj = {
                a: 42,
                say:  () => {
                    console.log(this.a);
                }
            };

            obj.say();
```

Comment: Most probably because `window` or the enclosing context doesn't have `a`

Comment: and how we can sole it? @gurvinder372

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Use `function` instead of an arrow function.  In arrow functions `this` references the function.  (try `console.log(this)`).

Comment: The arrow function has another scope for `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have explained, [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't have `this` values.

If you want similar concise syntax, you might want to try [ES6 Method Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) syntax which does have `this` values, and is shorter than a whole `function(){...}`

```
var obj = {
  a: 42,
  say() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
```

If you're structuring your app like this, it may make sense to go the whole hog and use [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

As a silly aside, it's also obviously possible that you can do the following:

```
var obj = {
  a: 42,
  say() {
    console.log(obj.a); //obj not this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use arrow function, since they don't have their own `this`. So, `this` (in case of arrow functions) will point to enclosing context.

```
 var obj = {
      a: 42,
      say: function() { 
          console.log(this.a);
      }
 };

 obj.say();
```

Comment: bind is not needed here

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: So, this means, that we really cannot use arrow functions inside object methods?

Comment: Depends on whose if you want to access `this` and whose `this` you want to access in that function. If there is no need to access `this` and `arguments` then there is no reason not to use arrow function.